# Traverse the mongo DB scheme in Mongoose JS

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm trying to find out if Mongoose.JS exposes subDocuments with in the .modelSchema.  The basic idea is that I want to generate a tree view of my database model.

For Exampe I a status schema that allow each status to have an array of questions that are made from a Question Schema.  My Mongoose Schema looks like this:

```
 var StatusScheme = new Schema ({
        StatusName:  {type: String },
        isClosed: {type:Boolean},
        Questions:[QuestionSchema]
    });

    var QuestionSchema = new Schema ({
       QuestionName:  {type: String },
       isRequired: {type:Boolean},
       QuestionType:{type: String }
    });
```

Now in my node.js app I want to iterate the schema to generate a tree of field names:

```
+StatusName
+isClosed
+Questions 
      +QuestionName
      +isRequired
      +QuestionType
```

I was exploring in the .modelSchemas[schema].tree object and I can get all of my field names the problem is I can't detect if the Questions array is really a different schema.  Does anyone have any insight into the object that may tell me this? Once I know that a field is really a subdocument I can recursivly iterate the entire schema to build my tree.

[image]

I think I may have found the link.  I can take a look modelSchemas object and dig into each path looking to see if the path has a caster object. If it does I can then fill it with the sub document data.

isClosed is not a subDocument and Questions is a subdocument.  It looks like Mongoose then includes the constructor for in in the modelschema.  Any thoughts on a better way to find the "tree" view or sub document relation within Mongoose.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Details can be found @ https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/4sBbi388msI

A Child schema must be defined before it is embedded as a sub document.

To find the sub document schema traverse to "CaseSchema.paths["MYRecipients"].options.type[0]"

The tree property also contains the nested relationship between schemas.